# How change component transition speed properly?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-transition

My goal is to provide transition speed via component properties and to set different values for growing and shrinking. So far I managed to achieve this by changing component style programmatically.

```
<script>
    let isFullHeight = false
    export let fullHeight = 400
    export let growDurationMs = 1234
    export let shrinkDurationMs = 567
</script>
<div id="container" style={isFullHeight ?
    `height: ${fullHeight}px; transition: height ${growDurationMs}ms;` :
    `transition: height ${shrinkDurationMs}ms;`}
    on:click={() => isFullHeight = !isFullHeight}>
</div>
```

This does the job, but maybe there is more idiomatic/elegant way to do this.

[Link to Svelte REPL with this example](https://svelte.dev/repl/e7df5f2a10c84a38a8840caf95a718f2?version=3.29.0)

Comment: probably just a matter of preference, but I would move style definition outside of template. I like having templates easy to read. https://svelte.dev/repl/4c0b3818578a461fb1e5e02cf595514c?version=3.29.0

Comment: @Daniel Looks much nicer! Thanks!

Comment: ...and I would use a function to convert an object representation to a style string, again, so that it is more readable

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on Daniel's comment above. The idea is to represent style as an object to make it more readable and then convert it to a style string.

```
<script>
  ...
  $: styleObj = isFullHeight ? {
      height: `${fullHeight}px`,
      transition: `height ${growDurationMs}ms`
    } : {
      transition: `height ${shrinkDurationMs}ms`
    }

  $: style = Object.entries(styleObj).map(([k, v]) => `${k}:${v}`).join(';')
```

Now the component looks much cleaner:

```
<div {style}>
  ...
```